# Retrofit injection using application class - Dagger 2 not working why?

Tags: dagger-2

Am trying to implement dependency injection with Dagger 2, the component is initialised at base level in the application class but the app freezes on launch, right on the line of code where am initialising the dagger component, below is my code.

The application class

```
    public class BaseApplication extends Application {

    private Context context;
    private Application application;

    private static BaseApplication baseApplication;

    protected AppComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        this.context = getApplicationContext();
        this.application = this;


        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this)).build();
        appComponent.inject(this);

        //initializedApp();
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public Application getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent(){
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

The AppComponent class

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {NetModule.class, AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(BaseApplication baseApplication);
}
```

The NetModule class

```
@Module
public class NetModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(){

        return RetrofitClient.getInstance().getRetrofit();
    }

}
```

The AppModule class

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private Application application;

    public AppModule(Application application){
        this.application = application;
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Application provideApplication(){
        return this.application;
    }
}
```

Gradle dependency configuration for Dagger 2

```
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"
```

The daggerVersion being `2.23`.

With this setup, the application starts but freezing with white screen, logs show that the program never runs beyond the appComponent initialisation in the `BaseApplication` even without injecting `Retrofit` anywhere in other classes. Can some body please help me figure this out, am basic to Dagger, I appreciate.

For more clarity this is my RetrofitClient class

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private final String TAG = RetrofitClient.class.getSimpleName();
    private static String BASE_URL = "";

    static {

        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
            BASE_URL = "http://0.0.0.0/api/v3/";
        }else{

        }

    }

    private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
    private Retrofit retrofit;


    private RetrofitClient() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(getOkHttpClient().build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return retrofit;
    }

    private OkHttpClient.Builder getOkHttpClient(){

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.authenticator(new Authenticator());

        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){

            loggingInterceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            builder.addNetworkInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

        }

        return builder;
    }

    private HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
        @Override
        public void log(@NotNull String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, s);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: BaseApplication is declared in my Manifest file.

Comment: what is `RetrofitClient.getInstance().getRetrofit()`

Comment: RetrofitClient is another class which basically instantiates Retrofit

Comment: I don't think your app stucks because of dagger

Comment: @odichdaniel does it produce error report? can you show us here?